# The Matcha can't swap in the Celo chain

Tags: gas

there is some wrong in Matcha when I try to swap in the Celo chain, and The Matcha Warns "Insufficient CELO balance". In fact, there are some celos in my wallet as gas. Is a bug with Matcha?
[image]

[image]